# Is there a limit to the number of SqlCommands that I can use with one SqlConnection?

Tags: sql, ado.net, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

Is there a limit to the number of SqlCommands that I can use with one SqlConnection?

ie

```
SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection();

myConn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString.ConnectionString;


SqlCommand myComm1 = new SqlComm("INSERT...");

SqlCommand myComm2 = new SqlComm("SELECT...");

SqlCommand myComm3 = new SqlComm("UPDATE...");

SqlCommand myComm4 = new SqlComm("UPDATE...");

SqlCommand myComm5 = new SqlComm("UPDATE...");

...

myConn.Open();

object confirmID1 = sqlComm1.ExecuteScalar();

object confirmID2 = sqlComm2.ExecuteNonQuery();

object confirmID3 = sqlComm3.ExecuteNonQuery();

object confirmID4 = sqlComm4.ExecuteNonQuery();

object confirmID5 = sqlComm5.ExecuteNonQuery();

...

myConn.Close();
```

Granted, I'm not trying to UPDATE anything that was INSERTED in the first command.

Comment: None! it is only limited to the client memory and Database server memory.

Comment: Thanks! That narrows down my debugging. =)